# How could I modify the response of this promise in this js function result before it being sent?

Tags: javascript

So I have This function

```
import service from "services/catalogs";

    export const getPaginatedAdminPublications = async (params: URLSearchParams) => {
      params.delete("sort");
      const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params.get("search"));
      if (searchParams) {
        const publicationId = searchParams.get("id");
        publicationId && params.append("ids[]", publicationId);
        params.delete("search");
        params.delete("id");
      }
      return service.getPaginatedAdminPublications(params);
    };
```

IT modifies the params and sends it to a function that returns a promise and this promise returns a result

```
  getPaginatedAdminPublications: (params: URLSearchParams) =>
    HttpService.get<API.PaginatedResponse<API.Publication>>(
      `${CATALOG_SERVICE_URL}/${CATALOG_VERSION_V3}/xxxxx`,
      params
    ),
```

The result returned is similar to

```
{
 data: [...],
 metadata: {
 page: 1,
 total_pages: 10
 }
}
```

But I want it to be

```
{
 data: [...],
 metadata: {
 page: 1,
 total_pages: 10
 }
pagination: {
 page: 1,
 total_pages: 10
}
}
```

SO ideally I want to somehow get the results and then still return some kind of promise but with the modified data.
With this pseudocode

```
export const getPaginatedAdminPublications = async (params: URLSearchParams) => {
  params.delete("sort");
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params.get("search"));
  if (searchParams) {
    const publicationId = searchParams.get("id");
    publicationId && params.append("ids[]", publicationId);
    params.delete("search");
    params.delete("id");
  }
  return service.getPaginatedAdminPublications(params).then(data => {
    return {
        ...data,
        pagination: {
            total: data.data.metadata.total_results,
        }
    }
  });
};
```

Is something like this possible? DOesnt seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already use async function:

```
export const getPaginatedAdminPublications = async (params: URLSearchParams) => {
      params.delete("sort");
      const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(params.get("search"));
      if (searchParams) {
        const publicationId = searchParams.get("id");
        publicationId && params.append("ids[]", publicationId);
        params.delete("search");
        params.delete("id");
      }
      const data = await service.getPaginatedAdminPublications(params);
      return {...data, pagination: {
            total: data.data.metadata.total_results,
        }}
    };
```

Comment: That just does what their current code does differently (which is to say, better, but still fundamentally the same). But they said their current code doesn't work, and indeed, neither it nor the above creates what they described they wanted.

Comment: Yeap, but I think the original code snippet also should work. Function getPaginatedAdminPublications is async and it means it already returns promise as the author asked.

Comment: They said they want two properties in the new `pagination` object, not just one, and that the names should be `page` (the one that isn't in this at all) and `total_pages` (this has `total`). This will literally produce exactly the same result that their own code produces. And yet, bizarrely, they've marked this as the right answer.

Comment: let's assume my answer as pseudocode and I think it is clear how to add new props in the result object.

Answer (score 1):

That's the right general direction, modifying it in the function before the return, but:

1. It would be simpler just to use `await`. It's almost never appropriate to use the old explicit promise callback stuff (`.then`, `.catch`) inside an `async` function. Certainly not in what you've shown.
2. Your data example has `total_pages`, but your code has `total_results`.
3. Your code just isn't creating what you've said you want. You've used `total` where you've said you want `total_pages`, and haven't provided `page` at all.

If the old code provided:

```
{
    data: [...],
    metadata: {
        page: 1,
        total_pages: 10
    }
}
```

and you want

```
{
    data: [...],
    metadata: {
        page: 1,
        total_pages: 10
    }
    pagination: {
        page: 1,
        total_pages: 10
    }
}
```

...then the end of the function should be:

```
const result = await service.getPaginatedAdminPublications(params);
return {
    ...result,
    pagination: {
        page: 1,
        total_pages: result.metadata.total_pages,
    }
};
```

...assuming the property is `total_pages`.